# Calculate the value of $I(9)/I(3)$ when $I(m)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1-2m\cos(x)+m^2\right)\,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

We are given that $$I(m)=\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln\left(1-2m\cos (x)+m^2\right)\,dx.$$
I could see that there weren't any standard techniques to calculate this integral directly so I concluded that there must be some kind of reduction formula to be derived.

What I did was to apply the King property in definite integrals ie.
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)\,dx.$$

This gave me $$I(m)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1+2m\cos(x)+m^2\right)\,dx,$$ then I added the two expressions for $I(m)$ to get
$$2I(m,x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1-2m^2\cos(2x)+m^4\right)\,dx,$$ i.e.,$$2I(m,x)=I(m^2,2x)$$.

So I thought that this should give us the value of $I(9)/I(3)=2$ and that was the correct answer, too; but what bothers me is that the second expression has $2x$ instead of $x$. So shouldn't that cause a change of limits and thus a problem?

Comment: It is $$\frac{\pi\log(81)}{\pi\log(9)}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How did you calculate the exact values?

Comment: $$\pi\log(1-2m+m^2)$$ is the general solution.

Comment: Your integral is a function of $m$, not $x$. So what you have is $2I(m)=I(m^2)$.

Comment: @AnuragA But from the definition of $I(m)$ it should've been $\cos x$ instead of $cos2x$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Could you please elaborate on what method you used?

Comment: Integrating by parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
2I(m)&=\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln\left(1-2m\cos (x)+m^2\right)+\ln\left(1+2m\cos (x)+m^2\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1-2m^2\cos 2x+m^4\right)\, dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\color{red}{2\pi}}\ln\left(1-2m^2\cos t+m^4\right)\, dt && (\text{let }t=2x)
\end{align*}

> Now use the fact that if $f(2a-x)=f(x)$, then  $$\int_0^{2a}f(x) \, dx
>  =2\int_0^af(x) \, dx$$

to get
\begin{align*}
2I_m & =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-2m^2\cos t+m^4\right)\, dt\\
     & = \int_{0}^{\color{red}{\pi}}\ln\left(1-2m^2\cos t+m^4\right)\, dt\\
&=I(m^2).
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\frac{I(m^2)}{I(m)}=2.$$

Comment: Really beatiful answer.

Comment: @Dog_69 Thanks.